# Identify if an element has rel="nofollow" attribute using CSS for selenium tests

Tags: css, selenium

I am using CSS selectors as the element locators for selenium test scripts.

Now, I want to check if an element has a `rel="nofollow"` attribute using CSS.

Does any one know how to check this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question isn't 100% clear on what you're trying to do, but I'll try to answer anyway.

If I'm reading you correctly, you're working within the Selenium script language, and you want to determine your the Selenium script that the page contains an `<a>` element that has `rel='nofollow'` attribute.

According to the [Selenium reference page](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0/reference.html), this should be possible, as Selenium supports most CSS selectors (the exception except pseudo selectors, but they're not relevant for you here).

It also supports DOM references and XPath references, so one way or the other you should be able to check just about anything.

For CSS, the syntax is `css=cssSelector`, so in your case this would be `css=a[rel=nofollow]`.

This selector will check the page for any `<a>` element with the `rel=nofollow` attribute. If you need to check if a *specific* element has this attribute, then modify the selector to include the ID or class of the element you want - eg `a#myspecificelement[rel=nofollow]`

This would be used with a Selenium command such as `assertElementPresent()` to check that the element is present, or a range of other possible Selenium commands.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you Spudley!!! it worked... I was trying the same thing but with an extra space between the <a> and the rel attribute.

Answer (score 1):

```
a[rel="nofollow"]
```

Won't work in all browsers.

A better solution would be to use jquery who selectors are supported in all browsers

```
$('a[rel="nofollow"]')
```

Comment: I think he's looking for a solution within the Selenium script, so this answer probably won't help.

Comment: I missed that in the question title, should I delete my answer?

Comment: if it doesn't help the questioner and you can't fix it so that it does then I guess yes, you could delete it. It's not mandatory but it might be a good idea. :)